# What code need to be implemented in order to satisfy this AWS S3 requirement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Need to create an AWS S3 inventory uploader API as described:

> The Service should have an HTTP POST endpoint to upload a new inventory.

```
    POST /inventory
    Body: empty
    Sample response
    {
        "upload_url": <s3-signed-url-for-upload>,
        "id": <asset-id>
    }
```

I am really new to AWS. Based on my current understanding, I thought all of these can be configured in API Console. Haven't understood the coding part to satisfy the requirement.

Comment: 1. Pick a programming language. 2. Install the AWS SDK for that language. 3. Use the SDK's S3 utilities to upload data to S3. You will also need IAM credentials for the application. I can point you to some documentation for your prefered programming language. I recommend against making raw HTTPS calls to the AWS API if you are new to AWS. The SDKs are much friendlier IMO.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide more information? For example, what is an "AWS S3 inventory uploader API"? What should it do? What have you tried so far and what difficulty are you experiencing? Do you have access to the person who gave you these requirements to ask for clarification?

Answer (score 0):

Simon,
[AWS SDK for Go](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/) is the document I found. Not sure if that was what you mentioned. Thanks